# How to copy data from a row to the the end column of the next N rows in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, awk

See example of data below.. I'm looking to add the Lat and Long to the end of the following rows until get to the next lat and long and then do the same. These lat and long values will change through the file.

**Current Data**

```
2010 02 15 19 29 2   0  LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27  
2010 02 15 19 29 2   1  1316.1 304  18.2  -9.5  -6.6    
2010 02 15 19 29 2   2  1300.1 202   2.2   1.3  -1.2    
2010 02 15 19 29 2   3  1284.1 188   5.2   1.4  -0.4        
2010 02 15 19 49 2   0  LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27   
2010 02 15 19 49 2   1  1316.1 277   9.5  -8.7  -8.4    
2010 02 15 19 49 2   2  1300.1 101   1.0  -1.4  -0.3    
2010 02 15 19 49 2   3  1284.1 195   2.8  -2.0   0.9    
2010 02 15 20 14 2   0  LATITUDE:  37.21  LONGITUDE: 90.27  
2010 02 15 20 14 2   1  1316.6 285   7.0  -1.2  -6.7    
2010 02 15 20 14 2   2  1300.6  46   2.8   2.1  -1.5    
2010 02 15 20 14 2   3  1284.6 194   6.2  -1.8  -0.4
```

**Required Data**

```
2010 02 15 19 29 2   0  LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27  
2010 02 15 19 29 2   1  1316.1 304  18.2  -9.5  -6.6 LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27    
2010 02 15 19 29 2   2  1300.1 202   2.2   1.3  -1.2 LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27    
2010 02 15 19 29 2   3  1284.1 188   5.2   1.4  -0.4 LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27        
2010 02 15 19 49 2   0  LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27   
2010 02 15 19 49 2   1  1316.1 277   9.5  -8.7  -8.4 LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27    
2010 02 15 19 49 2   2  1300.1 101   1.0  -1.4  -0.3 LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27    
2010 02 15 19 49 2   3  1284.1 195   2.8  -2.0   0.9 LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27    
2010 02 15 20 14 2   0  LATITUDE:  37.21  LONGITUDE: 90.27  
2010 02 15 20 14 2   1  1316.6 285   7.0  -1.2  -6.7 LATITUDE:  37.21  LONGITUDE: 90.27    
2010 02 15 20 14 2   2  1300.6  46   2.8   2.1  -1.5 LATITUDE:  37.21  LONGITUDE: 90.27    
2010 02 15 20 14 2   3  1284.6 194   6.2  -1.8  -0.4 LATITUDE:  37.21  LONGITUDE: 90.27
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/LATITUDE/{v=""; for(i=8; i<=NF; i++)v=v" "$i; print; next} {print $0, v}' File
```

Whenever the pattern `LATITUDE` is encountered, copy the part of the line (from `LATITUDE` till end of line) to variable `v`. For lines containing `LATITUDE`, print the line as it is and for others, print the line and then the previously saved variable `v`.

**Output**

```
AMD$ awk '/LATITUDE/{v=""; for(i=8; i<=NF; i++)v=v" "$i; print; next} {print $0, v}' File


2010 02 15 19 29 2   0  LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 19 29 2   1  1316.1 304  18.2  -9.5  -6.6      LATITUDE: 37.19 LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 19 29 2   2  1300.1 202   2.2   1.3  -1.2      LATITUDE: 37.19 LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 19 29 2   3  1284.1 188   5.2   1.4  -0.4          LATITUDE: 37.19 LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 19 49 2   0  LATITUDE:  37.19  LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 19 49 2   1  1316.1 277   9.5  -8.7  -8.4      LATITUDE: 37.19 LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 19 49 2   2  1300.1 101   1.0  -1.4  -0.3      LATITUDE: 37.19 LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 19 49 2   3  1284.1 195   2.8  -2.0   0.9      LATITUDE: 37.19 LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 20 14 2   0  LATITUDE:  37.21  LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 20 14 2   1  1316.6 285   7.0  -1.2  -6.7      LATITUDE: 37.21 LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 20 14 2   2  1300.6  46   2.8   2.1  -1.5      LATITUDE: 37.21 LONGITUDE: 90.27
2010 02 15 20 14 2   3  1284.6 194   6.2  -1.8  -0.4   LATITUDE: 37.21 LONGITUDE: 90.27
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import re

f1 = open('20151118b.dat', 'r')
lat = ""
while True:
    line = f1.readline()
    if len(line) == 0: break
    line = line.rstrip()
    match = re.search('(LATITUDE:.*)$', line)
    if match:
        # save the LATITUDE, and use it later
        lat = match.group(1)
        print('{}'.format(line))
        continue
    print('{} {}'.format(line, lat))
```